# How to create External object

Tags: lightning-connect

Can anyone tell me how to create external object?
After enabling the external object I dono how to create it?
I wanna create some sample external object in easier way?
Is there any simple demo on this?
Let me know if there is.

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Comment: you will find some guidance in this dreamforce video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67KIFdKshfs

Comment: @VamsiKrishna : I wanna do some realtime example on this topic

Comment: @VamsiKrishna For that How can I do..Please give me a source to do that.